# php find numbers in a string after and before the word "euro"

Tags: php, string, numbers, int

I have a string like `"9 mesi in cotone EURO 3+ss"` or `"9 mesi in cotone 3 EURO +ss"` and I would like to get the integer value before or after the word `EURO`, depends on string format (I don't know how the user will send it)
Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
if(preg_match('/(\\d+(?:\.\\d+)?)?\\s*euro\\s*(\\d+(?:\.\\d+)?)?/i', $string, $regs) and count($regs) > 1) {
    if(!$regs[1] and !$regs[2]) {
        // Invalid input
    } else {
        $amount = floatval($regs[1] ? $regs[1] : $regs[2]);
        // Do something with $amount
    }
}
```

The regular expression may need to be adjusted depending on the locale (space thousand separators, commas, etc).

If working with integer values, the regex simplifies to:

```
preg_match('/(\\d+)?\\s*euro\\s*(\\d+)?/i', $string, $regs)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to break it up into two regexes:

```
/(d+)\s*EURO/
/EURO\s*(d+)/
```

This should set you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+/',$string,$matches);
$values = array_shift($matches);
$lastnum = array_pop($values);
echo $lastnum;
```